# Google Chrome won't let me change the language at all

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, language

I just got a laptop and it had chrome installed with the Hebrew language, so I tried changing the language to English in Settings -> Advanced-> language-> add language and when I press the language text-button nothing happens, no dialog spinning thing. I tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it but it didn't help. I'm using windows 10 Home, System language is English Every thing is in English except Google Chrome.
I searched online for a solution but all of them are ancient or doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the display language

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Image Source: [WikiHow.com](https://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Default-Language-in-Google-Chrome)</sup>

Follow these steps...

> **Change language**
>
> 1. At the bottom right, select the time.
> 2. Select Settings [image: Settings] and then Advanced.
> 3. In the "Languages and input" section, select Language.
> 4. Find the language you want to use.
> 5. Optional: If you don't see the language you want, click Add languages. Choose the language you want, then select Add.
> 6. Next to the language you want, select More [image: More]. Choose how you want to use this language:
>
>    - **Show menus in this language**: Select Display Chrome OS in this language, then select Restart. The next time you sign in, menus will
>        show in the language you chose.
>    - **Show webpages in this language**: Select Move to the top to move the language to the top of the list. If you'd like Google Chrome to
>        automatically translate webpages, click Offer to translate pages in
>        this language.
>
> <sup>Note: Not every language works with your Chromebook's
>   menus.</sup>

Source: https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1059490?hl=en

Other resources

- [YouTube: How to change the default language in Google Chrome](https://youtu.be/n3qwYMRVpXA)

Comment: I don't know if I understood your answer,but, I think I have tried it. My problem is that I when I click the change language in Google Chrome It doesn't do anything at all, and I'm not using a Chrome book I'm using a laptop with Windows 10 home as I said above

Comment: Hey @MahmoodJazmawy, the process is same. Try uninstalling & deleting (profile/data) your browser. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\`

Comment: there is no file or directory with any thing related to data/profile/user